# Tensorflow: How to compute the square error between a tensor and a sparse tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, sparse-matrix

I have two tensors in `tensorflow`, one is a sparse tensor, called `A`, the other is a tensor, call `B`. I want to compute the square error between `A` and `B`.

When I perform:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.reduce_sum(tf.square( B - A))
```

then I got an error saying :

```
TypeError: Expected float32 passed to parameter 'y' of op 'Sub', got <tensorflow.python.framework.sparse_tensor.SparseTensor object at 0x7f42a10bdf90> of type 'SparseTensor' instead.
```

Then I tested:

```
tf.reduce_sum(tf.sparse_add(layer_Bi_12, - Bi))
```

the error says:

```
TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'SparseTensor'
```

Then I tested:

```
tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.sparse_add(layer_Bi_12, - Bi)))
```

The error says:

```
TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'SparseTensor'
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add sparse and dense tensors. You need to first convert the sparse tensor to a dense tensor, e.g.

```
dense_A = tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(A)
tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(B - dense_A))
```